# How to verify if the checkbox(which is label) is selected?

Tags: python, selenium

Currently I am working with a checkbox which is basically a label. Is there any way to check if it is selected or not?

```
<label for="type_all" style="font-weight:bold">All</label>
```

I know for checkbox I can use the below code to check if it is selected or not:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id(locater).is_selected()
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean it is a label? Can you show us the code used to generate it?

Comment: @Sithling, i have added how it looks

Comment: @user7242550 can you further expand the label tag and show what's inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the HTML you provided, you will see that the LABEL tag has a `for="type_all"` attribute and the `id` of the INPUT tag matches that `for` attribute, `id="type_all"`.

So... it depends on how you are finding the label. If you find it by the text of the label, you can `.get_attribute("for")` on the found element and then feed that as an id into `self.driver.find_element_by_id(id).is_selected()`. I would write it as a function something like the below

```
def is_label_checked(labelText)
    id = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[.,' + labelText + ']").get_attribute("for")
    return self.driver.find_element_by_id(id).is_selected()
```

and then pass in "All", "Workflow", etc.

Disclaimer: I don't do python so there may be syntax mistakes or it may not be very python-y.